# How to show url JSON data in SfCartesianChart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to draw a line chart fetching the data from a JSON from URL.
I know something about SfCartesianChart from https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/getting-started.

But I do not know How to develop a Line Chart using my JSON . Can somebody help . Thank you very much...

here json from URL is

[
{
"1": 150,
"2": 116,
"3": 123,
"4": 320,
.
.
.
"29": 231,
"30": 521
}
]

and here my code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  List<ChartData>  data1s = [

  ];



  Future<String> getJsonFromURL() async{
   String url = 'http://192.168.100.3/app/get_json.php';
    //String url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums';
    http.Response response= await http.get(Uri.parse(url) ,
       );

    return response.body ;

  }


  Future loadData() async{
    final String jsonString = await getJsonFromURL();
    final dynamic jsonResponse = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    for(Map<String , dynamic> i in jsonResponse){
      data1s.add(ChartData.fromJson(i));
      
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder(
      future: getJsonFromURL(),
      builder: (context ,snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
         return SfCartesianChart(


            zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
              // Enables pinch zooming
                enablePinching: true
            ),
            primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(


            ),


            // Chart title
            title: ChartTitle(
              text: 'Traffic',


            ),
            // Enable legend
            legend: Legend(isVisible: true,

            ),
            // Enable tooltip
            tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
            series: <ChartSeries<ChartData, String>>[
              LineSeries<ChartData, String>(

                  isVisibleInLegend: false,
                  animationDuration: 5.3,
                  dataSource:  data1s,

                  xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x as String,
                  yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
                  name: 'upload',
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  // Enable data label
                  dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
                    isVisible: false,

                  )),





            ],


          );
        } else{
          return Text('error');
        }
      },

    ),));
  }
}


class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y );
  final String x;
  final double y;





  factory ChartData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return ChartData(
      parsedJson['x'],
      parsedJson['y'],
    )  ;

  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do...
It's example

final dataMap = [ { "1": 150, "2": 116, "3": 123, "4": 320, . . . "29": 231, "30": 521 } ];

```
SfCartesianChart(
      primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
      series: dataMap.map((e) {
        return LineSeries<Map<String, int>, String>(
          animationDuration: 0,
          enableTooltip: true,
          markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(isVisible: true),
          dataSource: e.value.entries.toList(),
          xValueMapper: (Map<String, int> data, _) => data.key,
          yValueMapper: (Map<String, int> data, _) => data.value,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```